# Can you run 2 graphics cards with different OEM brands?

Tags: graphics-card

Can you run 2 graphics cards with different OEM brands?

And if there are any specific requirements to do so, please include them in your answer if you know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to accomplish: if you want true SLI (Nvidia) or Crossfire (AMD) support, you will have to check very thoroughly whether the exact cards will work the way you want them to (mainly depends on using the same GPUs but other restrictions may apply as well). Some FAQs for SLI support can be found [here (GeForce FAQ)](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq) and [here (Forum FAQ)](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/469402/sli/faq-quot-will-these-two-cards-work-in-sli-quot-sli-what-works-with-what-/). For SLI support different **OEMs** should not be a problem if the GPUs stay **exactly** the same.

Another solution (depending on the cards you want to use) judging from posts like [this](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-run-2-different-graphics-card-on-my-system) you could put them in as separate cards and use them as dedicated cards or PhysX card.

There was also [another solution](https://www.techradar.com/news/computing-components/graphics-cards/-gaming-changing-software-to-let-pc-gamers-mix-nvidia-and-amd-graphics-cards-1316830) which would offer SLI/Crossfire support with mixed setups, however, I could not verify if the program described ever made it to the market.